# finding the HEX code of a unicode string

Tags: regex, perl, bash, text, unicode

I have a unicode string which in addition to the normal characters, contains some strange chars. I've already found the "UTF-16 (hex)" encoding of some of these characters and removed them using some easy regex such as:

```
$text =~ s/(\s+\x{200C}+|\x{200C}+\s+)/ /g;
```

the above line is for removing unnecessary "Zero-Width Non Joiner spaces".
But I have some difficulties for removing the rest. I was wondering if there is a tool or command that you can give it your unicode string and it returns the equivalent "UTF-16 (hex)" encoding.
So, basically I want to feed it with my string (which contains the strange chars) and get the "UTF-16 (hex)" encodings of the chars, to be able to write some regexes for removing them.
I have to note that my texts are mostly in Persian and Arabic, not in English.

---

I got the answer of the above question, but the whole problem that I have still exists.
Actually, I have some characters like "Arabic Vowels" which I want to remove them from my string. And as I've found the code in perl of these characters I've wrote a line to remove them:

```
$text =~ s/\x{0618}\x{0619}\x{0621}\x{064B}\x{064C}\x{064D}\x{064E}\x{064F}\x{0650}\x{0651}\x{0652}\x{0653}\x{0654}\x{0655}\x{0656}\x{0657}\x{0658}\x{0659}\x{065A}\x{065B}\x{065C}\x{065D}\x{065E}\x{FC5E}\x{FC5F}\x{FC60}\x{FC60}\x{FC61}\x{FC62}\x{FE80}//g;
```

But strangely it doesn't work for all the cases. for example "Arabic Kasra (\x{0650})" should be detected and replace by this line of code, but it is not.
I've mentioned that for the characters in the line below it works:

```
\x{064B}\x{064C}\x{064D}\x{064E}\x{064F}\x{065A}\x{065B}\x{065C}\x{065D}\x{065E}\x{FC5E}\x{FC5F}\x{FC60}\x{FC60}\x{FC61}\x{FC62}\x{FE80}
```

while for the others it doesn't:

```
\x{0618}\x{0619}\x{0621}\x{0650}\x{0651}\x{0652}\x{0653}\x{0654}\x{0655}\x{0656}\x{0657}\x{0658}\x{0659}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UTF-16le and UTF-16be encodings of U+200C are `"\x0C\x20"` and `"\x20\x0C"`, not `"\x{200C}"`. This has nothing to do with UTF-16.

You simply want the hex representation of the character numbers. (It doesn't even have anything to do with Unicode really.)

- Hex of every character:

  ```
  print(sprintf("%v04X", $str), "\n");
  ```
- Sometimes hex sometimes octal of non-ASCII and non-printable ASCII characters:

  ```
  use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
  local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
  local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
  print(Dumper($str), "\n");
  ```
- Hex of non-ASCII and non-printable ASCII characters:

  ```
  my $lit = qq{"\Q$str\E"};
  $lit =~ s/([^\x20-\x7E])/ sprintf('\\x{%04X}', ord($1)) /eg;
  print("$lit\n");
  ```

Comment: Dear ikegami, thank you for the reply. It worked and now prints the character codes. But now I'm facing another problem. I have some characters like "ARABIC KASRA" which its code is \x{0650} and I have a regex for this character in my script to remove it from the string. But strangely it doesn't work and this character still exists in the string. I added some lines to my first post describing this case more clearly.

Comment: You forgot the square brackets in `s/\x{0618}\x{0619}\x{0621}.../.../`.

Comment: Oh, sorry for this mistake.